Requires Babel "^7.16.0", but was loaded with "7.9.0"
Error: [BABEL] unknown: Requires Babel "^7.16.0", but was loaded with "7.9.0". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing: "programmatic item$2")
node version 14.21.3
{
  "name": "Crews",
  "author": "Crews",
  "email": "",
  "licence": "UNLICENSED",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=6000 build",
    "build-max": "react-scripts  build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "ie 11",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/core": "^1.3.11",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.11",
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^6.1.7",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.63",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.7",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.18.7",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.38.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.38.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.6.0",
    "@unicef/material-ui-currency-textfield": "^0.8.6",
    "ag-grid-community": "^26.2.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^26.2.0",
    "array-move": "^2.2.1",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.17.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "clsx": "^1.0.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.10.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jss": "^10.0.0",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-chip-input": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "material-ui-datetime-range-picker": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^2.4.7",
    "material-ui-flat-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.41.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mui-datatables": "^2.13.3",
    "mui-nested-menu": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "notistack": "^2.0.3",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.9.359",
    "prismjs": "^1.25.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pubnub": "4.27.6",
    "pubnub-react": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "pubnub-react3": "npm:pubnub-react@^3.0.2",
    "pubnub7.2.3": "npm:pubnub@^7.3.0",
    "react": "~17.0.2",
    "react-advanced-cropper": "^0.19.6",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-aws-s3": "^1.3.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^11.0.5",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.8.0",
    "react-color-v2": "^2.19.8",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-currency-input-field": "^3.6.12",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-form-validator-core": "^1.1.2",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-image": "^4.0.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.0.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-joyride": "2.5.3",
    "react-material-ui-form-validator": "2.0.9",
    "react-mixpanel": "^1.0.5",
    "react-multi-date-picker": "^2.0.6",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.9.0",
    "react-paginate": "^6.3.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react-phone-input-material-ui": "^2.16.1",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-config": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-router-last-location": "^2.0.1",
    "react-s3": "^1.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.2",
    "react-share": "^4.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "1.11.0",
    "react-sortablejs": "6.0.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.3",
    "react-text-truncate": "^0.16.0",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^3.4.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.14.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "validate.js": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.2.0",
    "fslightbox-react": "^1.4.9",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "skeleton-placeholder": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  }
}


got this error
npm run build

but
npm run start

works perfectly

What is your actual question? Does npm run start also work after you deleted, moved away or at least renamed your node_modules and dist folders?
For the sake of completeness of your question please also add the name of the file that you are showing.

sorry npm run start works but when i try to make production build "npm run build" it gives error. it doesnot point to any files

you can list the transitive dependencies with npm ls --all to find the potential source of the wrong version, and as you mainly use the caret-ranging for your direct dependencies you should read the documentation about semver ranges to understand what it means: https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver#ranges

npm install --save-dev @babel/core

